# Finding Column value in GridView

Tags: asp.net, gridview, datarowview

I would like to get the column `(Description)` from `DataRowView`.I have the following code.

```
protected void GridView1_RowCreated(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
        {

            if (e.Row.DataItem != null)
            {
                DataRowView dataRowView = ???????????
                string description = dataRowView["Description"] as string;
            }

        }
```

How to replace `??????????` with appropriate code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `(DataRowView)e.Row.DataItem;`